# ios - How to select multiple cells on a single click (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm coding an iOS app and was wondering if its possible to select 3 cells at once when the user clicks on a single cell in a uitableview. So 3 would be the one they click and the 2 below. Is this possible and if so how would it be done? Thanks

How I currently check user clicks:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];


            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {

                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                });
            }
            else
            {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                  });

            }
        }
}
```

I also have

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

in my code, but the problem is that it doesn't allow me to select 3 at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about *selecting multiple cells on a single click* (I'm ignoring for the moment your insertRows / deleteRows stuff)...

Here are a couple examples of selecting multiple rows. You should have no trouble implementing this for your specifics:

**Objective-C**

```
// select ALL rows in Section 0
for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:iPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}

// select ALL VISIBLE rows
for (NSIndexPath *iPath in [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:iPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}

// select rows 2, 4 and 6
for (NSNumber *n in @[@2, @4, @6]) {
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[n integerValue] inSection:0];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:iPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}

// deselect all rows
for (NSIndexPath *iPath in [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:iPath animated:NO];
}
```

---

**Swift**

```
// select ALL rows in Section 0
for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
    let iPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}

// select ALL VISIBLE rows
for iPath in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
    tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}

// select rows 2, 4 and 6
for i in [2, 4, 6] {
    let iPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: iPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}

// deselect all rows
for iPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: iPath, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Is it similar in objective-c?

Comment: Also, how do i check which rows are currently selected? is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @apex - I'd suggest reading the docs... (even though I included this in the examples: `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]`) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview